# How to display random lines from excel sheet in android?

Tags: android, textview, readxml

I am reading 10 lines (each cell separately) from an excel sheet and am displaying it in `ListView`. But I have an idea: instead of displaying it in a `ListView`, I want to display in a `textView` randomly.
Here is the code for displaying in `ListView` I want it in `textView` Please help me

`import java.io.InputStream;`

`import java.util.ArrayList;`

`import java.util.List;`
`import android.os.Bundle;`
`import android.app.Activity;`

```
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ListView lv;

    Readme r;
    InputStream ims;
    ArrayList<String> a123 = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> ad;
    List<MyCustomPage> uuu = new ArrayList<MyCustomPage>();
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        r = new Readme();
        ims = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.tips);
        r.setInputFile(ims);
        try {
            System.out.println("t1");
            uuu = r.read();
            System.out.println("t4");

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        for (MyCustomPage m : uuu) {
            a123.add(m.getUserquate().trim());
        }
        ad = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, a123);
        lv.setAdapter(ad);
    }

}
`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do like this.

You probably already have a Collection. Let's say: 
ArrayList a;

You can

Collection.shuffle(a);

and then get the first element like this:

String line = ""+a.get(0);

everytime you shuffle the 0 element would be different

Comment: Yes .. Thank you .. it is shuffling in `ListView`But i have to show it  in textView Please help me

Comment: Once you get the line you could add it to the TextView:
tv.setText(line);